# Why does jwplayer buffer all entire movie and then playing it?

Tags: jwplayer

when I address a movie form the same server which `jwplayer` is located it buffers movie partly and playing during buffering.
But when I address a movie form different server it buffers all movie an then play it.
How to prevent buffering all and then playing?

this is my code:

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
  flashplayer: "VideoGallery/player.swf",
  file: "http://www.xx.com/xx.mp4",
  height: 270,
  width: 480,
  autostart: true,
  repeat: true,
})
```

Comment: Please provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

The video's moov atom needs to be at the beginning of the file to avoid this. Run your video through Handbrake with default settings, plus check "Web optimized," which is what repositions the moov atom.

http://handbrake.fr/

Even easier, use MP4 FastStart to reposition the moov atom - it does only that one thing, so it's very quick.

http://www.datagoround.com/lab/

Both utilities are free.